# TFS auto-merged a file that should have been manually resolved

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge

Got latest of a file on Monday, made modifications for two days, during that time the file has been checked in to the server with changes (roughly three check-ins).

I put the file into a shelveset, then got the latest of it to see if what everyone else had checked in was good. Eventually I unshelved my shelveset and continued to work on it. Then the pattern of shelving it, getting latest to check latest repeats throughout the day. Finally I checked it in, our gated check-in (fun times) said "Oh-no you don't" and re-shelves it for a successful build, after successful build the file is checked in and I'm never prompted to manually resolve.

Result is a that my check-in wipes out the changes from the past two days. fail.

Is my workflow wrong or is this a defect in TFS merge logic? I'd expect it to pop-up the resolve conflict dialog.